# Why we need multiple copy instruction in DockerFile for Asp.net core

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

Currently I am learning docker. I was going through the official documentation to create Docker images for ASP.NET Core that shows a DockerFile with following content

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "aspnetapp.dll"]
```

I successfully created the image and container eventually.

Here, in the DockerFile we have two COPY instruction.

first one, copy only the *.csproj files from that directory and paste it to /app directory inside docker image.

second one, copy all the other files files and paste it to /app directory inside docker image.

As far as understand, this tow `COPY` instruction in doing the same thing. so, instead of two different copy instruction, we can write one and it works fine. Like this -

```
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
```

so, why we are using two different instruction to copy files to docker image? Does it perform well with two copy instruction?

In the first `COPY` instruction, there is a comment `#Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers`. What it actually means or does?

Answer (score 7):

The reason is layers. In a Dockerfile, each command creates a new container layer. To speed the building of containers, Dockers caches these layers, where nothing has changed, meaning that command doesn't have to be run again; the cached layer is simply used. However, once something has changed, every single subsequent command in the Dockerfile must be run again, because that layer and all layers built on it are now invalid.

The reason for the two copy lines is that that pulling all the NuGet packages can take a while, and the only thing necessary for this to happen are the project files. Those project files aren't likely to change very often, so the NuGet restore layer can be cached. If you copied *all* the files, then any change to any file would invalidate the restore layer, meaning it would basically never be cached.